# Google Drive api react-native

Tags: javascript

I'm new in react-native and I need upload a image to Google drive, I try to use a google-drive-api-wrapper but I have a error 403 and I don't know what is the problem, someone could explain me How could I do this?, I show my code but I remove the webclientid

I try to guide me with this example
https://gist.github.com/luyx2412/2cddb9033d65403d595e069b95dad005

```
GoogleDrive= async() =>{
    await this.initialGoogle();
    GDrive.init();

    // GDrive.permissions.create(
    //     fileid, {
    //         role: "reader",
    //         type: "anyone"
    //     });

    const options = {
        title: 'Select Avatar',
        customButtons: [{ name: 'fb', title: 'Choose Photo from Facebook' }],
        storageOptions: {
          skipBackup: true,
          path: 'images',
        },
      };


    ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.uri) {
            // response.data is the actual image data.
            // response.type can give you the mime for pictures only
            // response.fileName for the name of the file.
            console.log(response.data);
            GDrive.files.createFileMultipart(
                response.data,
                response.type, {
                    parents: ["root"],
                    name: response.fileName,
                }, false);

        }
    });
}

initialGoogle = async () => {
    await GoogleSignin.configure({
        scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'],
        webClientId: '',
        shouldFetchBasicProfile: true,
        offlineAccess: false
    });

    // await GoogleSignin.signInSilently();
    //set api token
    GoogleSignin.getTokens();
}
```

error [Error: {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"insufficientPermissions","message":"Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes."}],"code":403,"message":"Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes."}}]

Comment: Have a look [here](https://support.google.com/business/thread/1858194?hl=en).

Answer (score -1):

You just need to get the image path, and then use the react-native-fs to read that image. After this pass the base64 image to GDrive wrapper.

```
RNFS.readFile(filePath, 'base64').then(res => {
        GDrive.files
          .createFileMultipart(
            res,
            "'image/jpg'",
            {
              parents: ['root'], //or any path
              name: newImageName,
            },
            true,
          )
          .then(response => {
            Alert.alert(
              'Image saved to Google Drive.',
              'Delete image from device?',[
                {text: 'Ok', onPress: () => this.unlinkImage(newFilepath)},
                {
                  text: 'Cancel',
                  onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
                  style: 'cancel',
                }
              ],
              {cancelable: false},
            );
          }).catch = err => {
          console.log('error', err);
        };
      });
```